# AngularJS: controlling ng-show from outside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm in the middle of learning Angular, and I am attempting to show or hide contents in a content div depending on side menu items being clicked.

```
<div id="side-menu">
  <h3>Side Menu</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="item in example">
    <p ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed">
      API Name: {{ item.name }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <h3>Content</h3>
  <!-- What do I have to add here to "connect" to "item in example"? -->
  <div ng-show="collapsed">
    <p>Debug: {{ item.debug }}</p>
    <p>Window: {{ item.window }}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What do I have to add to controller `ng-show` from the other div?

Comment: it looks like item.debug and item.window are outside the markup being generated using ng-repeat.  I would move them up/enclose them in the div that has ng-repeat on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$parent`:

```
ng-click="$parent.collapsed=!$parent.collapsed"
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/6vhH3/

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049480/what-are-the-nuances-of-scope-prototypal-prototypical-inheritance-in-angularjs) to understand the most important basics of Angular' `scopes`.

Comment: Close, but `item.debug` and `item.window` don't display anything. I updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evanemolo/6vhH3/1/).

Comment: @EvanEmolo ah , i see.. no problem , take a look : http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/hn55a/